# 403 Error in Amazon EC2

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, http-status-code-403

I tried posting this in the AWS forums but nobody has replied...

I can get the sample PHP app to work but not my own uploaded PHP app

I've been terminating and retrying numerous environments and instances the last day or two trying to get this going ( I just signed up for the free tier, and am using micro instance(s) )

Right now I have two environments in 'My First Elastic Beanstalk Application' (I've also tried this as two separate applications and got the same problem)

I can get SSH to work on both of them, but whenever I click 'view running version' from the elastic beanstalk section of the console I get '403 Forbidden' on the application I have uploaded, but am able to view the sample app in my browser just fine(same results whether they are in the same instance and/or environment, or if they are completely separate).

When uploading my PHP app in MacOSX I right click and choose 'compress' on the containing folder and create a .zip before uploading (it seems to uncompress fine when viewing the files through SSH)

I just launched the sample env along with my own env and just noticed a difference in the events, the sample app creates AutoScaling info, CloudWatch, and adds the instance it creates to the environment. My app doesn't say any of those, but it does say that it is available at ****.elasticbeanstalk.com, it creates and instance in my ec2 that I am able to connect to by ssh, and it says it successfully launched, but is still not available in the browser

As far as security groups, I have had them both set to be on the same group and I've tried them on separate groups either way I get the same error on my app but never the sample app.

on ssh i ran "ls -l" on var/www and saw that var/www/html has the same permission on each setup but it shows: lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16 Apr 6 23:07 html -> /var/app/current

I hadn't seem the html -> /var/app/current before, I went to that folder and found the permissions different, -rw-r--r-- was shown for all files on the sample PHP app, the directory containing my app was drwxr-xr-x -> and so I changed to drw-r--r-- and that didn't change the 403 errors...

I'm confused as to why the root directory of the app that I uploaded would be drwxr-xr-x doesn't that mean that all people have execute access? It seems like drw-r--r-- would be what I want. Giving me read/write access and everyone else just read access would seem like what a webserver should be right?

Either way, because this is over my head I'm terminating the instance in which I changed permissions just to be safe until I hear some advice from people..

For me it seems to be either file permissions or the fact that I don't see 'added ** instance' to environment on my PHP app's environment events, but I DO see it on the sample app, what am I not doing?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Aren't beanstalk apps supposed to be deployed with `git aws.push`?

Comment: ohhh, I missed that in the documentation, I will check into this when I have time to work it out tomorrow, thanks..

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_PHP.html

Comment: If you upload the files with beanstalk the files will be in directory named same as the zip file. So if you upload the files with `Test.zip` you can access your website with `example.com\Test\index.php`. You can avoid this by using git repo.

Comment: @Ruchit Rami, comment should be as accepted answer. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you just select all the files required, and then compress these into an archive, and upload through the Beanstalk App on AWS, they will be present in the root directory. As Ruchit Rami mentioned, if you compress the folder itself, the files will be present under a directory of the file name.